# iOS setting double value is wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, double

I have looked for an answer to this but could not find one.  I am developing an iOS 7 Application that uses an Interest Rate.  I have declared the following:

```
double InterestRate;
InterestRate = 3.9;
```

I set my button label to print Interest 3.9% and it works fine:

```
[btnInterest setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Interest %.2f%%",InterestRate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then when someone clicks on the button, I am sending this off to my PopOver Window like so:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"InterestController"])
{
    CC_InterestViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.delegate = self;
    [vc setInterestRate:InterestRate];   <---- BREAKPOINT HERE!!!!! (See Below)
}
```

Which is received by my PopOver like so:

```
-(void)setInterestRate:(double)rate
{
    interestRate = rate;
}
```

I then pull the 3.9 into different parts, so I can seperate them into a UIPickerview using two columns to select an interest rate.  The only problem is that I get:

3.89%  NOT 3.9%

So, I put a breakpoint at the point I am sending the InterestRate to the PopOver from the Segue, and I find that iOS reports my 3.9 as 3.8999999999999.

I am specifically setting it to 3.9.  Is there a better way of doing this?  I have found that basically if I set the setting to 3.9, it will then be reported by iOS as 3.8999999999999.

Any Ideas?

-UPDATE:

Ok, this is marked as a duplicate.  But, I am not using a float, but a double.  Not sure if it makes much of a difference, but there doesn't seem to be an answer.  If I declare double = 3.9, and then I look at the value it says it is 3.89999999999999.  This is definitely not the same.  So, my basic question is what is the best way to deal with this?  I need 3.9 to always equal 3.9, not 3.89999999999999.  If this is a duplicate question, how come the link does not give a simple straight forward answer as how to handle it, but a long winded explanation as to the problem.  I know there is a problem.  I am looking for an answer.

Comment: This has been covered many times. Floating point values are not exact.

Answer (score 1):

Its to do with the way `double`s (i.e., floating point numbers) are stored (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) question for more information.).

If you want accurate results use a [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There are the basic methods (add, subtract, multiply, divide) for performing [arithmetic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000179-SW3).

```
NSDecimalNumber *interestRate = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:39 exponent:-1 isNegative:NO];
```

To display a `NSDecmialNumber` as a string use a [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).